# Android: AlertDialog with custom style in MaterialTheme throws resource not found exception

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, android-styles, material-components-android

I have the theme `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`
in my styles as the main Apptheme.

My alert theme is

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/alert_bg</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>
    </style>
```

I build my alert dialogue like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AllowanceActivity.this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
```

when I run it without the style it runs properly but it crashes if I use any other style I've tried with all the themes extending alert `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert`
and `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert`
and `Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert`
 but I always get the error.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07005d
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2462)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2522)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5471)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07005d
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1432)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1412)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates(ResourceManagerInternal.java:252)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:139)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:411)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.attachToWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:311)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:272)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:232)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialog.getDelegate(AppCompatDialog.java:170)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialog.<init>(AppCompatDialog.java:59)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:983)
```

is anyone having the same problem or am I missing something

Comment: Try to Invalidate and Restart Android Studio, happens time to time

Comment: hey thanks I will try what theme should I be using in my styles anyhow?

Comment: try Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [MaterialAlertDialogBuilder](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md) which configures the instantiated `AlertDialog` with Material specs and theming.

Something like:

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context,
                 R.style.MyThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialAlertDialog)
            .setTitle("Dialog")
            //...
            .show();
```

Also use this parent style `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog`.